What are the properties creating a new QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer?
I would be create a new QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer, setting also the shape of symbol. At the moment, I set just the color and the outline.
layer_style = {}
    
layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (colorR,colorG, colorB)
layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
        
symbolLayer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(layer_style)

With this method is possible defining even the features' shape?
How can I access to the list of QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer properties?

Maybe you can try the method properties when you want to know the properties. QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer().properties() -> gives a map of all properties and their default values. Also I am not sure what you mean by 'setting the shape'. Can you clarify that? A QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer is just a colored fill style, there is no shape involved. It fills whatever shape your features of the layer have.

Thanks! So, in according with that you say, QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer is not useful for me. I would create a lot of pentagons: every point on the map, one pentagon. I tried with QgsMarkerSymbol but QGIS crashes. Are there other methods?

QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer is probably what you are looking for. It has a parameter for setting the shape, where you could use Qgis.MarkerShape.Pentagon in this case.
